# Theorem 5, Section 4.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, proof-explanation

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero, $c$ an element of $F$, and $n$ a positive integer. If $f$ is a polynomial with $\deg (f)\leq n$, then $$f=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{[D^k(f)](c)}{k!}(x-c)^k$$
>
> **Hoffman’s Proof:** By binomial theorem, $x^m=[c+(x-c)]^m=\sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}c^{m-k}(x-c)^k=\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{[D^k(x^m)](c)}{k!}(x-c)^k= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{[D^k(x^m)](c)}{k!}(x-c)^k$. Let $f=\sum_{m=0}^na_mx^m$. Since $D^k:F[x]\to F[x]$ is linear operator, we have $D^k(f)=\sum_{m=0}^na_m\cdot D^k(x^m)$. By theorem 2 section 4.2, $[D^k(f)](c)=\sum_{m=0}^na_m\cdot [D^k(x^m)](c)$. Thus $$\begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{[D^k(f)](c)}{k!}(x-c)^k &= \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{m=0}^n a_m\cdot \frac{[D^k(x^m)](c)}{k!}(x-c)^k \\ &= \sum_{m=0}^na_m\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{[D^k(x^m)](c)}{k!}(x-c)^k \\ &=\sum_{m=0}^na_mx^m \\ &=f\\ \end{align}$$

**Que:** **(1)** Where did we use $\text{char}(F)=0$ hypothesis? **(2)** I can’t prove change of order of summation.

Comment: For (1), it's when you divided by $k!$. If $\operatorname{char} F > 0$ and $k \geq \operatorname{char} F$, then $k! =0$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Ohhh yes. We’re working in generic field $F$, not $\Bbb{R}$. We need to extend definition of factorial. $n^*\in F$ denotes $\underbrace{1_F+\dots+1_F}_{n\text{ times }}$, and $k!=1^*\dotsb k^*$. If $\text{char}(F)=p\gt 0$ (i.e. $p^*=\underbrace{1_F+\dots+1_F}_{p\text{ times }}=0_F$) and $k\geq \text{char} (F)$, then $k!=1^*\dotsb p^*\dotsb k^*=0_F$. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: As for interchanging the order of summation, write the expressions down without the sigma operators. You'll see it's just the commutative property of addition and the distributive law of multiplication over addition.